# Running a Python Script Like a Built-in Shell Command

Tags: python, shell

I have gone through the following steps.

1. Made the file executable,
2. Tested that the file could be run with `./script1.py`,
3. Added the file's directory to the system `$PATH`.

However, at this point, am I supposed to be able to say `script1 arg1` and be able to run it like a built-in bash command or do I still need to set up an alias.

My quick hack is to set up an alias; however, I am not sure if this is redundant.

```
alias script1 = $HOME/dir/script1.py
```

Comment: is Python in the path ?

Comment: Yes it is in the path :)

Comment: At this point you are supposed to be able to say `script1.py arg1`.

Comment: There is a reason why you should not include `.` in your path: security. this very reason applies for your question too.

Comment: @mbratch If he didn't, he would not be able to run it with `./` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv script1.py script1
```

should do the trick. I won't recommend it though.

A better way is to add a symblic link:

```
ln -s script1.py script1
```

This way, you can add the link directly in some system path - probably `/usr/bin` - and won't need to change `$PATH` at all:

```
sudo ln -s script1.py /usr/bin/script1
```

Make sure it will not override any existing file.