# Run python script like a Linux command

Tags: python, linux, shell

I want to run my python function in console like this:

```
my_function_name
```

at any directory, I tried to follow arajek's answer in this question: 
[run a python script in terminal without the python command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587877/run-a-python-script-in-terminal-without-the-python-command)

but I still need to call `my_function_name.py` to make it work. If I call only `my_function_name`, the console will inform me `command not found` . I also tried to add a symbolic link with this answer: [Running a Python Script Like a Built-in Shell Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752935/running-a-python-script-like-a-built-in-shell-command) but it failed

`sudo ln -s my_function_name.py /home/thovo/test/my_function_name`

`ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/thovo/test/my_function_name/my_function_name.py’: File exists`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the name of the script to no longer have the `.py` extension.

Comment: I have never thought to remove the `.py` extension will make it work. It may be not quite right from my point of view only but it really worked. Thank you a lot! I will mark this answer as correct after few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Add this shebang to the top of your file: `#!/usr/bin/env python` and remove the file extension.